# Cannot "capture" Firebase snapshot in an array using a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I know there are tons of questions and answers on using Javascript promises to load returned Firebase objects, but I haven't succeeded in capturing the data in an array.

**The issue:** I've set up an array (`productArray` below) to iteratively take in values of a Firebase snapshot, but the array remains empty after exiting the `forEach` loop.

**database.js:**

```
  getProductList = function(){

    let productArray =[];

    loadFBData = function(){
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      return firebase.database().ref().once("value", function(snapshot){
        return snapshot.val();
    });
  }

  Promise.all([loadFBData()]).then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(product) {
      productArray.push(product.val());
    });
  });
}
```

**Question:** I think I'm using `Promise.all` wrong, but can't figure out how (also am new asynchronous functions). Thanks for any hints on how to get `productArray` to successfully load.

**Edit:** To elaborate, it seems `snapshot` is loading with the correct Firebase data, and the `forEach` is correctly looping through each item in `snapshot` but `productArray` becomes (or remains) empty outside of the `Promise.all` statement.

**Update** I implemented all the suggestions below and yet, the program will not stop long enough to build an array from the snapshot object. Last year I used Angularfire's `$loaded` function which was so effective in getting the program to wait so I don't understand why an ordinary JS `promise` won't work here. Does it make sense to resort to `timeout`? I even tried to combine alexmac's and Pointy's suggestions, but no cigar:

```
 getProductList = function(){

    let productArray =[];

    loadFBData = function(){
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      return new Promise(resolve => {
         firebase.database().ref().once('value')
            .then(function(snapshot){
               return resolve(function(snapshot){
                  productArray = Object.keys(snapshot).map((key, prod) => prod);
               });
            });
         });
   }

  loadFBData();
}
```

Comment: At first glance this code looks fine. It will only uses one promise, since you're loading the entire database. But that should work, unless I'm overlooking something. What's the problem you get with this code?

Comment: @Frank, thanks for responding. To elaborate, `snapshot` is indeed loading with Firebase data. The issue is (or must be) in that `forEach` loop, since (right after `Promise.all` and inside of `getProductList()`), `productArray.length` returns 0.

Comment: Your code isn't actually making a Promise at all. The `loadFBData()` function needs to return a new Promise with the current code inside the Promise callback. The function should pass the data retrieved to the `resolve()` function.

Comment: Why do you use `Promise.all` only for one element? Also if `firebase.database().ref().once` returns a promise, you don't need `Promise.all` at all.

Comment: @alexmac - you are right, I also just figured this out (having copied this solution originally from another SO answer - without understanding this usage.

Comment: @Pointy : ah of course! It's returning a `snapshot.val()` (just a value from a JSON object). Will `Promise.all()` not resolve on such a value? A quick test: `Promise.all([100]).then(function(result) { console.log(result); })` logs `[100]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background

I think you're missing an understanding of both promises and the Firebase SDK.

First, note that all Firebase SDK functions return promises, so there's no need to create your own. Second, Promise.all is for combining multiple promises. A single promises can be chained off of with a simple `.then()`.

I have a video on saving and querying data here: [Save and Query Firebase Data](https://youtu.be/7S5Om_tAAnI?list=PLdssc-pDiZ7MJeKr4k5r33jCGOT2H_iKB)

I have another video on promises here: [Promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GNo65p-y_o)

#### Loading Firebase

You should be initializing firebase at the very top of your page. It only needs to be initialized once, so don't initialize it within a function.

You can call `firebase.initializeApp(config)` just after loading the Firebase SDK on the page. Or you can reference Firebase Hosting's `init.js` as shown below.

#### Example

The following example loads the Firebase SDK, uses my testing db's `init.js` file to initialize firebase, then queries, manipulates and returns an array.

Note that Firebase doesn't support zero-indexed arrays, so everything you get back from Firebase will be an unsorted object. This example shows a few different ways of returning the data :)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://quiver-two.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/init.js"></script>    
    <script>
      function loadFirebaseArray(path) {
        return firebase.database().ref(path).once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
      }

      function toArray(items) {
        return Object.keys(items).reduce((array, key) => {
          const value = items[key];
          array.push({key, value});
          return array;
        }, []).sort();
      }

      loadFirebaseArray('stackoverflow').then(items => {
        console.log('items', items);

        const asArray = toArray(items);
        alert(JSON.stringify(asArray));

        const justTheValues = asArray.map(x => x.value).sort();
        alert(justTheValues);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example might look like this:

```
getProductList = () => {
  let loadFBData = () => {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      firebase.database().ref().once('value', resolve);
    });
  }

  let productArray =[];
  loadFBData()
    .then(snapshot => {
      productArray = Object.keys(snapshot).map((key, prod) => prod);
}
```

Here, I use *promisification* to create a promise for `firebase` query. So `loadFBData` returns a promise, I can create a promise chain or use ES7 async/await to wait until promise will be fulfilled to use result.

Comment: thanks I'm currently trying the ES6 solution and am trying to work through why I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function`

Comment: Add breakpoint or `console.log(snapshot)` before `productArray = snapshot` and check what is `snapshot`. According your code in question it must be an array.

Comment: `snapshot` is populated with a JSON object that looks to be in typical Firebase format: `{"key": {...}, "key": {...}, ...  }`. Where `key` is (in my case) a string representing an integer. I was wondering if somehow the object is too deep but in fact only has 2 levels: key and {obj}. Anyway snapshot is an object not an array.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through each item in the `snapshot` object and add/push these to an array. But if you say that the retrieved `snapshot` should be an array to begin with, then I'm probably dealing with an entirely different can of worms here.

Comment: Updated the answer, to iterate through `snapshot` properties.

Comment: Thanks, but again an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: prod.val is not a function` (frustrating). Two questions: I added the actual format of the object to my question - I guess your code should be good for that? And secondly: is the actual name used for `prod` as in `prod.val()` arbitrary?

Comment: Fixed, but I can't create a working code for you, I just shown you how fixed the general problem.